# Displaying text from an array into text box

Tags: arrays, swift

First off, I'd like to apologize for the newbie question, I'm trying to learn as I go with this. I've made a couple basic iOS apps but this is my first venture into macOS Storyboard apps with no formal training in programming.

I'm trying to create a program to help my partner (a writer by profession) with their creative blocks by displaying character, setting, and action attributes that can be used in a story. (Screenshots attached for a better representation)

I believe I have the basic window formatting down but I'm getting stuck on how to link the "Attribute" buttons to the text fields to display elements in the array. I just have placeholder elements until I get it working but ideally you would click the attribute button and it would display a random attribute from the array into the text box.

I've included what I was able to piece together so far but it's failing to build at the line to output to the text box and I can't seem to figure it out.

The error is:

> Cannot assign value of type `()` to type `String`

Any assistance is appreciated!

```
import Cocoa
    
class SecondViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var CharAtt1: NSTextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func CharAttBut1(_ sender: NSButton) {
        let array = ["Swift", "SwiftUI", "UIKit"]
        let randomElement = array.randomElement()!
        
        CharAtt1.stringValue = print("\(randomElement)")
        
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi Gloostik. Rest assured, noobie questions are more than welcome here. Yours seems pretty well asked, so it should get some positive responses!

Comment: `print()` is a function that doesn’t return a value hence the error message, since all you want to do is to assign the string you should remove the call and just do `CharAtt1.stringValue = randomElement`. Note that `ramdomElement` is of type String already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, the offending line of code is:

```
CharAtt1.stringValue = print("\(randomElement)")
```

It's got a fair number of issues. The most prudent is that `print` has a type of (approximately, I'm simplifying) `(Any) -> Void`. You're calling it, passing it a string (`"\(randomElement)"`). This will print the string to the console, but it will also return back a `()` (a.k.a. the empty Tuple, of type `Void`). As the error message suggests, this can't be assigned to `CharAtt1.stringValue`, which is expecting a `String`.

The fix is simple, don't call `print`:

```
// If you do want to print it, do it in a separate expression
print("\(randomElement)")
CharAtt1.stringValue = "\(randomElement)"
```

But there's another issue: `"\(randomElement)"` is useless. `randomElement` is already a `String`. You could just write:

```
print(randomElement)
CharAtt1.stringValue = randomElement
```

I'd say that `"\(anything)"` is kind of anti-pattern. If you need to convert something to a string, I think it's better to do so in a way that's more explicit about the conversion you want. E.g. using `String(anything)` (if such an initializer exists), or `String(describing: anything)`, or `String(reflecting: anything)` (depending on your usecase)